# Install private package in Docker with authentication

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an angular package in a private npm in azure and I need to install it in a docker. I don't know how to get an authentication token to connect to the private npm, I have .npmrc file.

My docker

```
FROM node:latest AS build
 
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

COPY .npmrc .npmrc
   
RUN npm install https://myprivate-npm/npm/registry/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}

RUN npm install
```

When I installed it locally, I ran these two commands from VS Code and they did the job

```
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false    
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

Comment: are you passing an ARG with an access token into your docker build command? Also your `https://myprivate-npm/npm/registry/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN} can just go in the .npmrc file

Comment: No, I don't know how to get an access token in docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an access token in docker:

ammend your .npmrc file with the following contents:

`//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}`

Ammend your dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest AS build
ARG NPM_TOKEN
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
RUN npm install
RUN rm -f .npmrc
```

Build your image replacing ${NPM_TOKEN} with your npm token `docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} .`

Everything here can be found in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/docker-and-private-modules)

Comment: Thank you but from where should I get this value NPM_TOKEN?

Comment: you can create access tokens using your npm account. Its one of the options in your profile area